# how to print the label and checked jquery checkbox items dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

how can i get the label and checked items dynamically in the table?

```
<div class="form_field odd">

            <label >Desktops </label> 



        <div class="form-group">

            <select id="ms" multiple="multiple">

            <option value="1">Made to Order(assembled)</option>

            <option value="2">HP/Compaq</option>

            <option value="3">IBM</option>

            <option value="4">Lenovo </option>

            <option value="5">etc</option>



        </select>

        </div>

    </div>



    <div class="form_field even">

            <label for='server'>Servers </label> 



        <div class="form-group">

            <select id="ms1" multiple="multiple">

            <option value="1">Made to Order(assembled)</option>

            <option value="2">Compaq</option>

            <option value="3">IBM</option>

            <option value="4">etc</option>



        </select>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: but i have almost 23 checkboxes and user can select any of the checkbox items, then how can i get the  label test.

Comment: Its the same question I wasn't even aware I gave the answer to the previous one.